# How could be useful the softforks field that provides the RPC command getblockchaininfo?

Tags: json-rpc, blockchain.info, nodes, soft-fork, command-line-options

When I execute the command getblockchaininfo I see useful information but I don't understand how to be useful the information that is displayed through field softforks, the example below:

`bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo`

```
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 623195,
  "headers": 623195,
  "bestblockhash": "00000000000000000010596cbf2767824bbb4828b331f2533938f1650ba96202",
  "difficulty": 13912524048945.91,
  "mediantime": 1585317240,
  "verificationprogress": 0.9999826836456495,
  "initialblockdownload": false,
  "chainwork": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000df5647c802d85a8d1fea0b0",
  "size_on_disk": 305751602545,
  "pruned": false,
  "**softforks**": {
    "bip34": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 227931
    },
    "bip66": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 363725
    },
    "bip65": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 388381
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 419328
    },
    "segwit": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 481824
    }
  },
  "warnings": ""
}
```